# how to activate cname widcart Ssl for amazon s3

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3, cname

I Set Amazon s3 to my custom Domain Like the below

cdn.example.com.    CNAME   s3.amazonaws.com

I have purchased a Wildcart SSL From Namecheap and installed via Cpanel

Now I need to Activate https://cdn.example.com

When request https://cdn.example.com the SSL error is Coming in broswer as normail SSL is not install Non secured page

how To Set WILDCART SSL To CNAME subdomain

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? We're having the same problem.

Comment: not yet . Now is used Cloudfront for https:// . If I find a Solution i will let you know.

Comment: @Citizen : I got the answer i setup successfully. if you need help please say

Answer (score 2):

Make a Cloudfront Distribution for the Corresponding bucket.

Then install the sll on the cloudfront

You Can See how SSL is installed on cloudfront here

https://bryce.fisher-fleig.org/blog/setting-up-ssl-on-aws-cloudfront-and-s3/

Comment: Thanks, yes, I followed the same guide and got it set up.